# Suggestions are not showing for DataSearch when the search needs to happen on elastic field of array type

Tags: reactjs, elasticsearch, reactivesearch

My elastic search provides the results as an elastic array. Here is how the mappings look.

```
 "positions": {
            "properties": {
              "en": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "fr": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              }
```

So this gives me result as below.

```
"companyinfo.positions.en": " Chain Corporate, Food Services, Service Manager, Restaurant Manager, Cybercafé Manager, Internet Café Manager, Assistant Bar Manager, Assistant Manager, Restaurant Assistant Manager, Banquet Manager, Bar Manager, Cafeteria Manager",
```

I am using value as **"companyinfo.positions.en"** for the **dataField** property of the DataSearch control.

Currently I am **not** using the onSuggestion property, rather I am expecting  DataSearch to provide me the suggestions automatically. But it is not giving me any suggestions. But the control gives me the search results as expected.

```
<DataSearch 
    componentId={id}
    dataField={'companyinfo.positions.en'}        
    placeholder={'Search Jobs'}                
    URLParams={true}
    autosuggest={true}        
    showClear={true}                
    />
```

If I provide any other textfield as a dataField for the DataSearch control, then I get the suggestions, why not it works for the elastic array fields.

Please suggest what I can do to get the suggestions correctly. If I will have to use the onSuggestion property, how do I provide the field name as for the label, I can't provide the field name.

Comment: Could you try adding these custom analyzers https://opensource.appbase.io/reactive-manual/getting-started/data.html#custom-analyzers. They help `DataSearch` in fetching suggestions. Also if you can create a codesandbox example, I can tell better :)

Comment: @DivyanshuMaithani please take a look at this one https://codesandbox.io/s/m5wmk6rqyy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an issue with nested array fields in the library and was fixed in `v2.8.2`. [Changelog](https://github.com/appbaseio/reactivesearch/blob/dev/packages/web/CHANGELOG.md)

Comment: Yes after updating the package the suggestions worked fine for me. Thanks.